# How to use TouchBar - Slider in Mac Catalyst?

Tags: swift, macos, uikit, appkit, mac-catalyst

I'm trying to add Touch Bar support for Mac Catalyst app.

And the NSSliderTouchBarItem is marked as available for catalyst, but the doubleValue of the slider is not available. Is there another way to get value from it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

More great uses  Mhd Hejazi's Dynamic [Library](https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Dynamic)

```
    touchBarVolumeSlider = NSSliderTouchBarItem(identifier: identifier)
    touchBarVolumeSlider.label = "V"
    touchBarVolumeSlider.action = #selector(changeSliderValue)
    touchBarVolumeSlider.setValue(0.5, forKey: "doubleValue")
    Dynamic(touchBarVolumeSlider).slider.setContinuous(false)
```

Now the action only calls changeSliderValue when the slider stops moving.  I look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/appkit?view=xamarin-mac-sdk-14) to get details on the underlying methods and properties.

Answer (score 0):

To get the position of the slider, use this:

```
    @objc func changeSpeed(sender: NSSliderTouchBarItem) {
        let value = sender.value(forKey: "doubleValue") as! Double
        print(value)
    }
```

To set its position:

```
    slider.setValue(0.5, forKey: "doubleValue")
```

The value is between 0 and 1

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work to set "isContinuous" false, which is true by default.   Anyone know what the correct key or keypath is?